# script Send command with SH

Tags: bash, sh, splunk

I would need a .sh script that allows me to read only the second line of a file and then send it to machine B.

Example file:

`timestamp_pippo.csv`

```
"Row1_skipped"
"Row2_send_to_machine"
```

the file is in the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Splunk\var\run\splunk\csv
```

only the second row "`row2_send_to_machine`" (contains a unix command) must be sent to machine B

once the command has been sent, the file timestamp_pippo.csv must be deleted.
can you help me? I'm not familiar with .sh

what I've managed to create so far is only this:

```
for a in $(C:\Program Files\Splunk\var\run\splunk\csv cat timestamp_pippo.csv|grep -v Row1_skipped);do
 ssh unix_machine@11.111.111.11 $a
 done
```

Comment: `head -2 timestamp_pippo.csv | tail -1` will give you the second line from the file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I would like to keep the "for" cycle for future needs. I made some changes:

`path=C:\Program Files\Splunk\var\run\splunk\csv*_pippo.csv 
for a in $ (path | grep -v Row1_skipped); do 
@echo a 
ssh unix_machine@11.111.111.11 $a
 rm a 
done`


based on my needs, do you think it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I've solved with this script:

`path="/home/weblogic/testCSV/*.csv"
for a in $(ls -lrt $path|awk '{print $9}');do
           #echo $(head -2 $a | tail -1)
           ssh unix_machine@11.111.111.11 $(head -2 $a | tail -1)
           rm $a
           #echo "file $a removed"

           break
           #echo "send command"
done`

Steps:
-check the file 
-execute the old file
-remove the file

The command we have to send to machine B is in the second line of the file timestamp_pippo.csv.

Another question:

How I can authenticate me in the machine B?
BR

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to retain the for loop:

```
for cmd in $(head -2 timestamp_pippo.csv | tail -1); do ssh <machine> $cmd; done
```

Though tbh, this is bad - if you actually extend this and use the loop, you will be doing multiple connects to the ssh machine. Better to create the batch file you want, then do one ssh and run the batch. Here's a decent explanation of running a local script on a remote host: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313000/run-local-script-with-local-input-file-on-remote-host

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I made some new changes based on what you told me.
`path=C:\Program Files\Splunk\var\run\splunk\csv\*_pippo.csv
for a in $(head -2 path| tail -1);do
echo $a 
if [[ -e "$a" ]];
then
     ssh unix_machine@11.111.111.11 $a
     #echo "send command"
     rm $a
     #echo "$a file removed"
else
     #echo "$a file don't exist"
     exit 1
fi
done`



Do you believe that I am now in line with the initial requirements?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I thought your file contained commands you wanted to run on the remote machine, not filenames? Or are they names of batch files containing commands? Basically, are you trying to copy file $a over, or run the command stored in string $a?